# Javascript - Cordova - Android - Return base64 encoded canvas drawn with local image file

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I need to write a new HTML file from a string using file system, I'm using Cordova 2.4.0. . That HTML would have some images loaded from a local folder, so because I need just one file (a HTML without png/jpg images alongside it) I'm trying to encode this images and apply them through CSS as background images (The CSS code is embeded in the same String, future HTML file). Well, the way I make these modifications to the string is by using functions returns. For example:

```
padding-top: 5%; background-image: url(' + agregaImagenLocal('../img/ESTELAR.png') + '); background-color: white;
```

The function "agregaImagenLocal(pathToLocalImage)" :

```
 function agregaImagenLocal(pathToLocalFile) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOculto');
    var imagen = new Image(150,100);
    canvas.width = imagen.width;
    canvas.height = imagen.height;
    var contextoCanvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
    imagen.onload = function () {
        contextoCanvas.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
        urlImagenLocal = canvas.toDataURL();
    }        
    imagen.src = pathToLocalFile;
    return urlImagenLocal //???????

}
```

I was doing this without the "onload" event, so it returned a blank image. But with this function inside the "onload" I don't know how to return the base64 encoded image to the first function.

Comment: So your application already has the image source, and you wish to convert that to base64?

Comment: yes, is it stupid? -.-'

Comment: Not at all... In my PhoneGap application, I am converting to base64 at the time the local image is loaded, then setting the src to the base64 image. Let me see if I can modify my code to work for your needs.

Comment: Yes, you can by modifying your function.. I will add this code to an answer. Just a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function to convert an Image (by file path) to Base64:

```
function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png');
        callback.call(this, dataURL);
        // Clean up
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Once the conversion is made, you can use jQuery to set the background CSS using the Base64 code.

```
var imageUrl = ""; //Your Local Image Path HERE

convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function(base64Img){
    $('.output').css("background-image", base64Img);
}
```

This will set the source of an element with the class 'output' to the base64 image.

Comment: Here's a working JSFiddle, which is very similar, that may assist you further... http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/

Comment: I have to make modifications because of the way I was doing it, so I'm now figuring out how to implement it, so I'll tell you if it doesn't. But apparently I can make the modifications, also deppends on the fact I'm almost a beginner in javascript and hybrid apps (and all kind of apps, I mean). But thank you for your time.

Comment: The most difficult thing to me is how to modify the string/css without the return, because is not a actual css file, but a string containing on it also the html. I'm not very good at programing logic, so if doesn't work is because of my own faults, not by your answer. That's the reason a gave you an "answered", because I notice your code is right. So I think that now deppends on me the implementation of a good coding, based on your help.

Comment: Good luck! If you need any more assistance, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: In the code above (your second block of code), Is there a missing parenthesis? (the one that closes the convertImgToBase64 function... ?)

Comment: No, You would place that code where you want to execute the conversion.. You can wrap this code (2nd block) in your page load call, or a button click, etc.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but I'll tell you the truth; I just couldn't understand the jsfiddle and I have to present this product soon, so I encoded the images in http://www.base64-image.de/ and paste them. Thank you so much for your kindness and avilability. I need more time to learn.